# How do I modify the canonical import example for Hue's Sqoop app, to make it re-runnable?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, hue

I've tried out the cannonical import example for hue's sqoop app - looks something like this:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/11/sqooping-data-with-hue/

this example, however, is not repeatable - on second and later run attempts, it gives an error message (sqoop won't overwrite contents of existing directories - so it refuses to run once the directory is created during the original import).

how do i modify this example, to make the import process scheduleable/re-runable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is using Sqoop2, [Oozie Workflows](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/61597968730/hadoop-tutorials-ii-3-schedule-hive-queries-with) don't support Sqoop2 action yet, only Sqoop1. Some workarounds are explained [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/sZOLZF6DEx8).